# how to configure karma along with ng2-bootstrap while writing test cases for angular2 application

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, ng2-bootstrap

I have made below changes and getting socket error

In karma.conf.js

```
{
    pattern: 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap/**/*.js',
    included: false,
    watched: false
}
```

In karma-test-shim

```
map:{ 'ng2-bootstrap': 'base/node_modules/ng2-bootstrap'}
packages:{'ng2-bootstrap': {defaultExtension: 'js'}}
```

Comment: What error do you get ? What is missing ? ng2-bootstrap uses moment.js for the date picker component, you might need to configure that also.

Answer (score 1):

This piece of code solved the problem

'ng2-bootstrap': { format: 'cjs', defaultExtension: 'js', main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js' },

'moment':{format: 'cjs' }